# Capture clicks in Flash adds

Tags: javascript, flash, events, onclick

I am trying to track the exit clicks of the users in the adds in my page.

Can I somehow capture with Javascript the click event of a user in a external Flash add I have inserted in my page?

I have been searching and trying by myself, but it seems like the flash object inside of my page is a black box, where I could not access anyway.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Google analytics allows this behavior:

http://www.google.com/support/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55520